# "of high quality" or "of a high quality"

Tags: indefinite-article, phrase-choice, zero-article

I would like to know which expression is the right one:

> they are of high quality OR they are of a high quality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that *of high quality* is correct, but surprisingly, both the phrases are in use! [Ngram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are%20of%20high%20quality%2Care%20of%20a%20high%20quality&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Care%20of%20high%20quality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20of%20a%20high%20quality%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Care%20of%20high%20quality%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Care%20of%20a%20high%20quality%3B%2Cc1) *'...are of high quality'* more frequently used as compared to *'are of a high quality...'*

Furthermore, [COCA](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) lists only one example with *'...are of a high quality'* whereas there are 14 for the other phrase.

Personally, I'd prefer using *zero* article in such instances.